# Javascript is working in console, but not in contentscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, content-script

This is a follow up question on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964236/inserting-a-link-to-a-dupe-in-the-close-popup-here-on-stackoverflow). Short version is: I'm trying to insert a dupe link (close vote as dupe here on Stack Overflow) into the textfield in the close vote popup using javascript (Chrome extension). The previous answer got me a bit further and seems the solutions. However the answer on that question works in console, but doesn't work in my chrome extension for some reason.

The problem is: when opening the vote to close popup here on Stack Overflow on a question and clicking the dupe reason. I can run the following code in the console:

```
var $dupeQuestion = $('#duplicate-question');
$dupeQuestion.val('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php');

var e = $.Event('keydown', { keyCode: 64 });
$dupeQuestion.trigger(e);
```

And as already mentioned this works. The link is inserted into the textbox and the Stack Overflow JS kicks in to retrieve the question. However when I try to run that exact same code in my extension it only kinda works:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cvhelper-dupelist li', function() {
  var $dupeQuestion = $('#duplicate-question');
  $dupeQuestion.val('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php');

  var e = $.Event('keydown', { keyCode: 64 });
  $dupeQuestion.trigger(e);
});
```

Kinda works means: the link is inserted in the textbox, but the Stack Overflow script to retrieve the question doesn't kick in. So I am totally clueless what could be wrong. Perhaps there is a difference somewhere when using console vs contentscript? Anything else?

I've created [a download](https://github.com/downloads/PeeHaa/cv-pls/cv-pls.zip) with a very simplified version of the extension at github.

Comment: maybe you are overwriting stackoverflows javascript, try to use setTimeout for testing it, because console script is executed in a insulated area, i think.

Comment: Is it important that the `console`-run script all be one line in the question? It makes it kinda hard to read and compare against the other. Also, I didn't know you could use `$.on()` with `document`. Not saying you can't, just didn't know you could.

Comment: Yes, you can also try to replace that with $(document).ready(function (){$('.cvhelpeler-dupelist li').click(function(){});}

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa - Just for you to know, you can type in lines in the Developer tools (console) by pressing Shift + Enter.

Comment: @JaredFarrish You can run it on document. And the one-liner is just for easy copy-pasting in console to test.

Comment: @Tearsdontfalls That's not what `on()` does.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I've updated my question with a download link to the simplified extension which may help.

Comment: Do you have a link to the project on github?

Comment: @JaredFarrish lemme push the latest changes

Comment: @JaredFarrish [Stable](https://github.com/PeeHaa/cv-pls) and [dev](https://github.com/PeeHaa/cv-pls/tree/dev) (the one with the issue). And [this](https://github.com/downloads/PeeHaa/cv-pls/cv-pls.zip) is the simplified extension with the issue.

Comment: Ok, great. I'll take a look, I've been wanting to take a look at Chrome extensions as it is.

Comment: @JaredFarrish If you need more info about my issue just say so. And if you need more info about extensions in general just drop me a line in [php chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php).

Comment: *Chrome extension to help cleanup Stack Overflow.* - That made me chuckle. I'll be interested in taking a look at it. At least through the main app channels, I've been surprised there aren't more SO-related apps available. Stackapps notwithstanding. I'm also seeign if your on chat, I have a question about using git.

Comment: I can't find the `.cvhelper-dupelist` element on stackoverflow pages...

Comment: @Derek That's because it is added by my extension.

Comment: @Derek basically what happens is that I add a list with possible dupes and the user selects a dupe and it should be inserted into the textbox

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reasons is that your Content Script is executed before other scripts load and it messed up other things. If it is the reason, then try:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
]
```

It might work, but I really don't know. `:/` Try it and see if it fixes.

Comment: Aw... Maybe the problem is in some where else hidden in your code.

Comment: I've updated my question with a link to the simplified extension. I've also added all relevant links in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965248/javascript-is-working-in-console-but-not-in-contentscript#comment14317171_10965248).

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa - I will take a look at it later.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is the only thing that would come to mind:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cvhelper-dupelist li', function() {
  var $dupeQuestion = $('#duplicate-question');
  $dupeQuestion.val('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php');

  setTimeout(function() {
      var e = $.Event('keydown', { keyCode: 64 });
      $dupeQuestion.trigger(e);
  }, 1);
});
```

It would basically let the click handler finish before attempting to trigger the keyDown.